# Substituir valor campo src com javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu estou tentando modificar uma função nesta loja virtual [clique aqui](https://roupasemvarejo.com.br/bermuda-tactel-masculina-100-estampas).

Nesta página do produto, no código `html` da página, na galeria de imagens, existe o seguinte código que é referente a imagem principal:

```
<a class="thumbnail min-h" href=""><img class="main_image" src="https://roupasemvarejo.com.br/image/cache/catalog/Produtos/masculino/bermuda-tactel-masculina1-228x228.jpg" id="zoom_01" data-zoom-image="https://roupasemvarejo.com.br/image/cache/catalog/Produtos/masculino/bermuda-tactel-masculina1-500x500.jpg" title="Bermuda Tactel Masculina 100 Estampas" alt="Bermuda Tactel Masculina 100 Estampas"></a>
```

Se você utilizar o chrome e usar a função para inspecionar a página, irá ver que eu clicar na miniatura das demais imagens, o valor do campo `data-zoom-image` é alterado, porém o valor do campo `src` permanece, fazendo com que a imagem principal não seja substituida. Mas ao passar o mouse sobre a imagem principal, o zoom que aparece é referente a miniatura da imagem que foi clicada.

Eu gostaria de ajuda com uma função em javascript que alterasse o valor no campo `src`.

Eu tentei a função abaixo, mas não funcionou:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.thumbnail').click(function(){
        $('#zoom_01').attr('src',large_image); //large_image é a variável que o campo data-zoom-image utiliza
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está selecionando o elemento errado. Se quer selecionar a imagem em:

```
<a class="thumbnail min-h" href=""><img class="main_image" src="https://roupasemvarejo.com.br/image/cache/catalog/Produtos/masculino/bermuda-tactel-masculina1-228x228.jpg" id="zoom_01" data-zoom-image="https://roupasemvarejo.com.br/image/cache/catalog/Produtos/masculino/bermuda-tactel-masculina1-500x500.jpg" title="Bermuda Tactel Masculina 100 Estampas" alt="Bermuda Tactel Masculina 100 Estampas"></a>
```

A imagem acima é a miniatura. Você está selecionando erradamente a imagem que aparece no zoom, que está funcionando normalmente.

O seletor correto é este:

```
$("a.thumbnail .main_image")
```

Logo seria:

```
$("a.thumbnail .main_image").attr("src",large_image);
```

Comment: Sim, a imagem do zoom está correta, mas ao clicar em outra imagem nas miniaturas a imagem principal não é atualizada, somente a imagem no valor do campo `data-zoom-image` que é correspondente ao zoom.

Comment: @Wendell Não funcionou com a dica acima?

Comment: funcionou sim, porém acabei tendo outro problema: Ao clicar na miniatura a imagem principal fica com proporção 500x500px, como pode ser visto na url ao inspecionar a página, essa proporção é somente para o zoom, a proporção correta sem o zoom deveria ser de 228x228px. Existe uma maneira de alterar isso?

Comment: @Wendell Tenta esse: `$('a.thumbnail .main_image').attr('src', $(this).find("img").attr("src"));`

Comment: @Wendell Estava olhando aqui seu site, o problema é que não tem nenhuma referência dessa imagem tamanho 228px.. só a de 74px e de 500px... se o nome da imagem é padronizado e só muda o valor do tamanho, vc pode fazer um replace nesse valor

Comment: obrigado pela sua ajuda, eu percebi isso e fiz um replace para mudar o tamanho, porém como vc havia visto o site não está gerando a imagem em tamanho 228px, estou procurando o erro que está causando isso.

Comment: @Wendell Cria um atributo no link tipo `data-img="url_da_imagem_228"` que fica fácil de puxar